# Regex to match the string after variable character

Tags: python, regex, ruby

I am trying to figure out regex (compatible with Python or Ruby) to match the string after string and a variable character or space, like so.

```
shop_item bananas 
shop_item: bananas
shop_item.bananas
shop_item  bananas
```

I really need bananas :-)

I tried to `/^(\S*) (.*)/` but this one is not matching all the situations properly.

Update: using new data the name can be like this banana-nana or underscore, so it is not only a character, but almost anything (not space or .).

Thanks for the advice

Comment: Is each item always going to look like `shop_item[maybe some separator][or a space][or both][some item]`?

Comment: How about `(?:\w+)\W+(\w*)`? https://regex101.com/r/lL52fg/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending how your "Bananas" string would look like maybe a positive lookbehind?

```
(?<=\W)\w*$
```

[Link to test](https://regex101.com/r/pIle9X/1/)

Answer (score -1):

Now I noticed that you first line contain whitespace after `bananas`. To deal with it I would do in `Python`:

```
import re
txt = '''shop_item bananas 
shop_item: bananas
shop_item.bananas
shop_item  bananas'''
items = re.findall(r'(\w+)\W*$', txt, re.M)
print(items)  # ['bananas', 'bananas', 'bananas', 'bananas']
```

`$` combined with `re.M` flag matches end-of-line.